# How to find lowest value along with the date for given set of data(date-value pair) in Google Sheet Formula?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, min

I have below data in date-value pair format in Google Sheet:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/8/2021 | 1301.85 |
| 1/11/2021 | 0 |
| 1/12/2021 | 1320.05 |
| 1/13/2021 | 1291.55 |
| 1/14/2021 | 1287.45 |
| 1/15/2021 | 1270 |

I'm looking for a google sheet formula that will return the lowest value which is greater than 0 along with its associated date. That means I'm trying to get the output as below: 1/15/2021  1270 instead of 1/11/2021 0

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
={A1:B1; INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:B, B2:B>0), 2, 1), 1)}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about the header row? Because I'm getting the data set along with the header row.

Comment: Can I replace the range A:B with the formula which generating the data?

Comment: I'm using this below:
=Index(SORT(FILTER(A:B,B:B<>0),2,1),1)
But I'm trying to put this formula along with the formula which is generating the data range, so that I can get the data in one go. So in the above formula when I replace A:B with my formula which gives the data range, it's not working.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet or formula?

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
=SORTN(FILTER(A:B,B:B>0),1,,2,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to replace the range A:B in the FILTER with the formula which is generating the data?